# QT C++ - How to open Windows Media Player with a Playlist active?

Tags: c++, qt, playlist, windows-media-player

I have a project where the requirements are to open windows media player with a playlist. The playlist is built from selected files.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I found, it appears easy to open a WMP instance.  However I'm not sure how to build the playlist or insert it on WMP startup. Any Thoughts ?

```
#include "atlbase.h"
#include "atlwin.h"
#include "wmp.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CComBSTR bstrVersionInfo; // Contains the version string.
    CComPtr<IWMPPlayer> spPlayer;  // Smart pointer to IWMPPlayer interface.

    hr = spPlayer.CoCreateInstance( __uuidof(WindowsMediaPlayer), 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER );

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = spPlayer->get_versionInfo(&bstrVersionInfo);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Show the version in a message box.
        COLE2T pStr(bstrVersionInfo);
        MessageBox( NULL, (LPCSTR)pStr, _T("Windows Media Player Version"), MB_OK );
    }

    // Clean up.
    spPlayer.Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562624(v=vs.85).aspx

Halfway down the page it lists:

`/Playlist PlaylistName`

> Open the Player and play the specified playlist.

Launch the program with `QProcess` and specify the arguments.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html

Hope that helps.

EDIT: If you still want to use the WMP API, you could look into:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563405(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563242(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563547(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks im gonna check this stuff out, is that Vash the stampede ?

Comment: You are correct.  Good job on knowing your anime pop culture.  :)